# Vagrant up doesn't work

Tags: laravel, ssh, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

When I run 'vagrant up', I am getting below errors. I haven't any idea. Previously I was run without error. I sold SSD Harddisk and took it. When I want setup again, encountered this errors.

```
/Users/KerimCaglar/sites/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:106:in `read': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/KerimCaglar/KerimCaglar/.ssh/id_rsa (Errno::ENOENT)
from /Users/KerimCaglar/sites/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in configure'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/kernel_v2/config/vm_provisioner.rb:72:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/kernel_v2/config/vm_provisioner.rb:72:in `add_config'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/kernel_v2/config/vm.rb:321:in `provision'
from /Users/KerimCaglar/sites/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:103:in `block in configure'
from /Users/KerimCaglar/sites/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:102:in `each'
from /Users/KerimCaglar/sites/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:102:in `configure'
from /Users/KerimCaglar/sites/Homestead/Vagrantfile:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `load'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:113:in `block (2 levels) in load'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:107:in `each'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:107:in `block in load'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:104:in `each'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:104:in `load'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/vagrantfile.rb:28:in `initialize'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:740:in `new'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:740:in `vagrantfile'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:486:in `host'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:208:in `block in action_runner'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `run'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:473:in `hook'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:722:in `unload'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/bin/vagrant:177:in `ensure in <main>'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/bin/vagrant:177:in `<main>'
```

Comment: The error is right there on the first line of your output. Where is `/Users/KerimCaglar/KerimCaglar/.ssh/id_rsa`?

Comment: I also get this problem - /path/to/some/folder/folder/file.ext (Errno::ENOENT) and the 'folder' is clearly duplicated. The Vagrantfile does not have the path duplicated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The important part of that error is here:

> No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/KerimCaglar/KerimCaglar/.ssh/id_rsa

You either haven't generated your SSH key or you need to specify the correct path.

If you look at your `Homestead.yaml` file you should see the path to your ssh key:

```
authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

If your SSH key is somewhere else you'll need to specify the correct path. Otherwise you'll need to generate it.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your@email.com"
```

[Source](http://laravel.io/forum/06-04-2014-problem-launching-vagrant-on-homestead).

Comment: i run this command and generate two file but i didnt find any .ssh folder on my pc(im using windows)

Answer (score 2):

The key part of the error is the duplicated path:

`/Users/KerimCaglar/KerimCaglar/.ssh/id_rsa (Errno::ENOENT)`

Notice how the username is mentioned twice. I have found this to be caused by:

1. Specifying too much path in the Vagrantfile, e.g.

   config.vm.provision "file", source: "**KerimCaglar**/.ssh/id_rsa",     destination: ".ssh/rd_rsa"
2. You're invoking `vagrant up` from a subdirectory - `cd ..; vagrant up` will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got Git installed, all you have to do is simply go generate your ssh key through the GUI. Help -> Show Key

[image]